# How to copy specific columns?

Tags: excel, vba

When I push a button, rows of one sheet are copied to another sheet.

I want to copy data from column A to column Y, not the whole row.

My code:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
x = 15
Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
    If Cells(x, 1) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Copy
        Rows(x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(erow)
    End If
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    x = x + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will copy just columns A to Y.  I have also refactored it to get rid of the need to constantly switch between sheets.

```
Sub Button4_Click()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim erow as Long

    'Calculate starting rows
    x = 15
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Do While .Cells(x, 1) <> ""
            'Your current code replaces the source data with its values so
            'I have left that functionality in by using the following line
            .Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value = .Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value

            'The next line copies values to Sheet2
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & erow & ":Y" & erow).Value = .Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value

            'increment row counters
            x = x + 1
            erow = erow + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```